# Changing some shopware theme files with FTP won't affect website

Tags: shopware, shopware6

In a website build in shopware, I'm changing the theme files but when I changed for example the (meta.twig) file it is affecting the website, but when I edit (index.twig) it is not affecting it.
What could cause this problem?

Comment: Maybe cached content in your browser, try reloading the page with CTRL + F5 or R + F5 as it removes the cached files from the website.

Comment: Yes i have tried that, but it still doesnt show anything i add on it

Comment: Have you also cleared the cache on the server? You can do that from the Administration with `Alt + C` on Windows and `Control + C` on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your Twig file is cached, either by the symfony build-in twig cache or the full page cache. You might need to clear the cache in the administration or via console (`php bin/console cache:clear`).

You can deactivate the http-cache that is enabled by default in the installation package in your .env-file by setting `SHOPWARE_HTTP_CACHE_ENABLED` to `false`. The twig cache can be deactivated in the `vendor/shopware/platform/src/Core/Framework/Resources/config/packages/twig.yaml` with `cache: false`

Comment: I did change these attributes with FTP but the files still dont seem to change on the website

Comment: Did you assign your theme to a sales channel and did you install it in the plugin manager?

Comment: Yes it is assigned to a sales channel, but i dont know about installing it in the plugin manager!